# changing specific elements only under a specific class

Tags: html, css

New to CSS . I am experiencing a problem where i only want to change elements within a class only. I have looked online and tried many ways but i really dont know whats the problem.

Here is the html part:

```
<nav class = "choice">

    <ul>

                <li><a href="#">Sign-in</a></li>
                <li> | </li>
                <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
                <li> | </li>    
                <li><a href="request.html">Request</a></li>
    </ul>

</nav>

<footer class = "footer">

        <h2>Site Map</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
            <li><a class = "active" href="about.html">How it All Works</a></li>


            <section id = "copy">
            <p>&copy; 2018. All Rights Reserved.</p>
            </section>
        </ul>
</footer>
```

Here is the css:

```
.choice{

    text-align : right;


 }
   ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 1em;
            width: 200px;
            color:white;
        }

        li a {
                display: block;

                color: #00ff00;
                padding: 8px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
        }
        li a.active {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
        }

        li a:hover:not(.active) {
            background-color: #555;
            color: white;
        }

        #copy{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            color: #fff;
            line-height: 40px;
            font-size:  1em;
            text-align: center;
            bottom:0;


        }
```

So long story short. I just want to change the elements "li" and "ul" under the class choice only  but because i have same elements in the footer part, the selectors for the footer part will also change the elements in the class choice. What is the correct way to change g a specific part of a element only for that class ? Thank you

Comment: Just select with the `.choice` as an ancestor? `.choice > ul` for example, is that what you mean?

Comment: i tried it didnt worked. @Chaska fixed it! Thank you though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `.choice` to select elements under it:

```
.choice {
  text-align : right;
}
.choice ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 200px;
  color:white;
}

.choice li a {
  display: block;
  color: #00ff00;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.choice li a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.choice li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

#copy{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size:  1em;
  text-align: center;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. This is what i needed. Learned something new!

Answer (score 0):

Add `.choice` to all `ul` and `li` in CSS which you want to change.

For example: `.choice ul`, `.choice li > a`, `.choice li > a.active`

Below is working code:

```css
.choice {
  text-align: right;
}

.choice ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 200px;
  color: white;
}

.choice li > a {
  display: block;
  color: #00ff00;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.choice li > a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.choice li > a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

#copy {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="choice">

  <ul>

    <li><a href="#">Sign-in</a></li>
    <li> | </li>
    <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
    <li> | </li>
    <li><a href="request.html">Request</a></li>
  </ul>

</nav>

<footer class="footer">

  <h2>Site Map</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="about.html">How it All Works</a></li>


    <section id="copy">
      <p>&copy; 2018. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </section>
  </ul>
</footer>
```